# php paypal button by using sandbox account

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to make paypal button by using sandbox account.
When I create this button, this button does not link to paypal when I click the button.
I cannot find why it doesn't work.
Could you help me?

```
$pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="wholee_1330463367_biz@googlemail.com"/>';

//this one using foreach statement.
$pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'.$x.'" value="'.$product_name.'">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_'.$x.'" value="'.$price.'">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_'.$x.'" value="'.$each_item['quantity'].'">';

//Finish the Paypal Checkout Btn
$pp_checkout_btn .='<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="XXX">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/eshopProject/home.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to The Store">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/eshopProject/android.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="UK">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
    </form>';

//in HTML form
<div align="center">
                    <?php  echo $pp_checkout_btn; ?> <br>
                    <a href ="home.php"> go to home page</a> 
            </div>
```

Comment: can you describe what's happening after clicking the button?

Comment: return value is invalid.

Comment: I mean it happened nothing when I click the button.. I am really wondering, and I can see the error which is 'Undefined variable: pp_checkout_btn in' this line: <input type="hidden" name="business" value="wholee_1330463367_biz@googlemail.com"/>

Comment: Maybe you could post the generated markup on your page. If some of your php values aren't set it could cause the html to behave improperly.

Comment: oh..when I try to put form statement in html, it works fine. However, it goes to paypal login page instead of displaying the cart.. what is wrong with it?

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to escape the newlines within the statement or use multiple strings like `'<form ...>' . *\n here* '<input ...>'`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start with:

```
$pp_checkout_btn = '<form ...';
```

You can't use the string append operator to initialize a string.